# Extract and normalize date from string for the proper text mining

Tags: machine-learning, classification, text-mining

I am trying to perform string delivery classification (X: delivery_string, y: delivery_string_relevance (values 0 or 1)). I am using DTM (document term matrix) for the feature extraction, and experimenting with text-mining algorithms. However, I still believe that I can preprocess my raw strings better (before creating the DTM) by extracting delivery dates and obtaining one common format representation for all of them. Any suggestions on good date parsers? ***datefinder.find_dates()*** in Python is doing quite a decent job, however still fails for some cases, such like when string contains "delivery time 10 - 12 days" it extracts it as 10-12-2017.

**Sample data (language used Dutch):**
beschikbaar vanaf 04 okt // beschikbaar vanaf: 05-08-2017 // 8 - 9 weken // 8 - 9 werkdagen // 8 dag(en)

Answer (score 1):

The best option is [dateparser](https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser), whose goal is to parse natural language dates with support for Dutch. There is another package [recurrent](https://github.com/kvh/recurrent) which does natural language parsing of dates focusing on recurring events.